# Best way of getting key & value from Spinner

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

There are many methods for getting `Key` & `Value` from `Array`.

But what is best way getting `Key` & `Value` from an `Array` in `arrays.xml` like `key => value` via spinner?

**arrays.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="settings_listofitems">
        <item name="1">item1</item>
        <item name="2">item2</item>
    </string-array>  
</resources>
```

When i use code in below i get only `item value`. But i need item `key value` too:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String itemvalue = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settings_listofitems)[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `Keys` and `Values` both in separate Arrays, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="settings_listofitems_keys">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="settings_listofitems_values">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item1</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

And then parse them like this :

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String itemvalue = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settings_listofitems_values)[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
String keyvalue = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settings_listofitems_keys)[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
```

I hope this helps.